# Upon Length contraction according to the principles of Relativity, does the Centre of mass of the body change? If yes how does it affect us?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics

What happens to the CM of an object experiencing Length Contraction?
And does the CM change based on if the frame of reference is Inertial or Non-Inertial?

Comment: A body does not experience length contraction- its proper length does not change.

Answer (score 1):

There are several thought experiments one might invent to address this question. For example, consider a long beam pivoted on a knife edge directly below the beam's centre of mass, so that the beam is perfectly balanced and sits horizontally. Imagine that the beam is observed from a reference frame moving relative to it at a significant speed. Since the beam is balanced, its centre of mass has to remain above the knife edge when judged from the moving frame.